# How can I call the constructor?

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I dynamically create instances of my objects in the custom linq provider I am building using this call:

```
 object result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
```

My T type implements an abstract class that has a constructor to take an instance of another object (T is essentially a wrapper). My question is - is there a way I can explicitly call the non-default constructor so I can get rid of this:

```
 MyEntity entity = result as MyEntity;
 if(entity != null)
    entity.UnderlyingEntity = e; //where e is what I am wrapping
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just supply the constructor arguments after the `Type` object, like so:

```
object result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the variadic overload [Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) and it will use the best matching constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could just call `object result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), e);`